# What is the best way to change the partitioner in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

Currently we are using random partitioner and we want to update that to murmur3 partitioner. I know we can achive this by using sstable2json and then json2sstable to convert your SSTables manually. Then I can use sstableloader or we need to create new cluster with murmur3 and  write an application to pull all the data from old cluster and write to a new cluster.

is there a other easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way, its a pretty massive change so might want to check on if its absolutely necessary (do some benchmarks, its likely undetectable). Its more a kind of change to make if your switching to a new cluster anyway.

To do it live: Create a new cluster thats murmur3, write to both clusters. In background read and copy data to new cluster while the writes are duplicated. Once background job is complete flip reads from old cluster to new cluster and then you can decommission old cluster.

Offline: sstable2json->json2sstable is pretty inefficient mechanism. Will be a lot faster if you use an sstable reader and use sstable writer (ie edit SSTableExport in cassandra code to write a new sstable instead of dumping output). If you have smaller dataset the cqlsh COPY command may be viable.